# Potential Memory leak in Suse

Tags: linux, tomcat, memory-management, memory-leaks, suse

I've a SUSE server running tomcat with my web application (which has threads running in the backend to update database). 
The server has 4GB RAM and tomcat is configured to use maximum of 1GB.

After running for few days, the `free` command shows that system has only 300MB free memory. Tomcat uses only 400MB and no other process seems to use unreasonable amount of memory.
Adding up the memory usage of all process (returned from `ps aux` command) shows only 2GB is in use.

Is there any way to identify if there is leak at system level?

Comment: Any linux system is doing as less work on memory management as possible. That means used memory which can be set free keeps in RAM till the space is needed or the data can be reused. Dont worry its normal.

Comment: Linux will utilize any/all available (i.e. not being used by other programs) memory for file system cache. It is better to use it for file system cache that let it sit unused.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The problem here is, after few days, tomcat stops responding because it's unable to reserve more memory. Looks like the system cache is not getting freed.